how to use cli progress bar to show progress in cleaning steps without for loop?
I'm confused how to use cli cli_progress_bar() and cli_progress_update() outside of the demo use case that they have in their documentation here (below is an example)
https://cli.r-lib.org/articles/progress.html#the-traditional-progress-bar-api
If you wanted to show the time it takes to download a package do you first down load and record the total time, then use the progress_bar() and progress_update() to replicate the time using the for loop to show the actual time?
If I just had a script that went through a few cleaning steps (eg return a series of interim objects each with different cleaning steps done) how could I use progress bar to show how far along the cleaning steps the function is?
Below is an example of script that has some basic steps where I want to show the progress bar updating as each preparation step is completed without using a for loop.

library(tidyverse)

prepare_data <- function(){
 cli_progress_bar("Cleaning data", total = 3,clear = FALSE)

dat1 <- diamonds |> count(cut)

 cli_progress_update()
 
dat2 <- diamonds |> 
  group_by(cut) |> 
  summarise(
    mean_price=mean(price)
  )
 cli_progress_update()

dat3 <- left_join(
  dat1
  ,dat2
  ,by=join_by(cut)
)
 cli_progress_update()
 
 return(dat3)
}

prepare_data()

What I'm expecting to see is that after each cleaning step the progress bar updates like the in the example below
library(cli)

clean <- function() {
  cli_progress_bar("Cleaning data", total = 100)
  for (i in 1:100) {
    Sys.sleep(5/100)
    cli_progress_update()
  }
  cli_progress_done()
}

clean()


You should show us some code that corresponds to the cases you don't understand.  We can't suggest how to fix the code you showed us, because it's fine.

hi! updated with an example of what I'm trying to show -- thanks

You didn't call cli_progress_done() at the end of your function, but I think that's not the issue:  the issue is that your function is too fast.  cli says that it won't show the progress bar at all unless the time exceeds 2 seconds.  You can change that limit using options(cli.progress_show_after = 0) to always show it, or some other number (in seconds) for a different limit.

thank you! I missed that in the documentation. Can you submit that as an answer and I'll accept it?

The docs for cli says that it won't show the progress bar at all unless the time exceeds 2 seconds.  Your function probably finished too quickly. You can change that limit using options(cli.progress_show_after = 0) to always show it, or some other number (in seconds) for a different limit.
You also missed the cli_progress_done() call at the end, but that probably isn't the issue here.
